# Ajax File Upload not works for jquery created form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Here is my code:

```
$('#form_div').append(
'<form class="image-up" action="image_upload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" class="custom_images" name="file" >
<input type="submit" value="submit" class="ajaxSubmit"/>
</form>');
```

I can't upload the file using any type of script. What is wrong in my code?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$(function() {
    $('#form_div').append('<form class="image-up" action="image_upload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"><input type="file" class="custom_images" name="file" ><input type="submit" value="submit" class="ajaxSubmit"/></form>');
});
```

Content which we insert using append() should be in single line.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
$('#form_div').html(
'<form class="image-up" action="image_upload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" class="custom_images" name="file" >
<input type="submit" value="submit" class="ajaxSubmit"/>
</form>');
```